# Difference between survival and hazard

Tags: survival, hazard

I am trying to find an intuitive explanation of the difference between the hazard and survival rates?  Are the two the same thing but expressed differently?

Comment: survival rate = the proportion (e.g percent) being "alive" at a certain time point.

hazard = the instantaneous risk of experiencing the event.

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of the _difference in meaning_ of the two parameters or for an intuitive explanation of their relationship?

Comment: @DilipSarwate an intuitive explanation both both would be great.

Comment: See [What is a hazard rate?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/121931/17230), [Implication of Hazard Rate?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/136014/17230), [Proof of relationship between hazard rate, probability density, survival function](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/58046/17230) &
[Intuition for cumulative hazard function (survival analysis)](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/60238/17230).